# Why is "1 2 3" a valid Scheme expression?

Tags: scheme

This is valid Scheme

```
1 2 3
```

and returns 3. But this is not valid

```
(1 2 3)
```

and neither is this valid

```
(1) (2) (3)
```

It makes sense that the last two are not valid. But I don't see how the first one should be valid? Can someone please explain?

Comment: Which Scheme? Which standard (R5RS, R6RS, R7RS, ...)? Which implementation and operating system?

Comment: The answer is the same in RnRS for n=0 to n=7.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) of your implementation is reading a non-empty *sequence* of expressions and evaluating all of them and giving the *sequence* of results. (I believe that this behavior of the REPL is implementation specific. [R7RS](http://r7rs.org/) does not mention it in its §5.7. It might vary with other implementations of [Scheme](http://schemers.org/) and I never used it; I agree with [coredump's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32930914/841108) that it may be a fancy and useful feature)

Scheme is able to return and handle several values, e.g. with `call-with-values` & `values` ; see also [this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html)

So technically **`1 2 3` is *not* a *single* expression**, but a *sequence* of three expressions. A call to `(read)` won't give you such a sequence. And on guile 2 on Linux `(+ 2 (read)) 55 66` gives *immediately* two results `57 66`, not three (after *waiting* for input).

Read also about [call/cc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation), [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation), and [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). There might be some indirect relation (how does *your* REPL deal internally with them when `(read)`ing expressions....)

Answer (score 3):

The REPL is reading multiple forms in sequence (this is also how Common Lisp implementations work). Given that the user entered multiple forms, what else could happen?

- displaying an error would be correct, but unhelpful
- discarding previous/next forms would be confusing

IMHO the behavior of reading all the given forms as-if they were in an implicit `progn` is the most useful for the user. It is also consistent with how files are read, and allow you for example to paste the content of a file directly into the REPL.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is valid because it is considered a simple expression. Scheme doesn't do anything with it and just echoes it back to you. This is true not only for numbers, but also for all constants including strings, symbols and even lists (if you quote them to create an actual list rather than a function call). For ex. if you type in `'(1 2 3)`, it will be just echoed back to you without being interpreted.

The way scheme, and generally other lisps, evaluate expression can be described by two broad rules (and this is probably a naive interpretation):

1. If the entered expression is a constant (a string, number, symbol, list or something else), the constant itself is the value. Just echo it back.
2. If the expression is of the form `(procedure arg1 ... arg-n)`, find the value of `procedure`, evaluate or find the values of all the arguments (arg1 to arg-n), and apply `procedure` to the arguments.

More details are available at [Evaluating Scheme Expressions](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/start.html#./start:h3) chapter in the the book [The Scheme Programming Language 4e](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/).

Comment: But your two items do not represent the first interaction, where there are 3 expressions one after the other.

Comment: That seems to be a quirk/feature of the scheme repl (I am guessing here). After evaluating each of the three numbers as separate expressions, it discards the two earlier outputs and just prints the last one. Some quick checking with other expressions in the repl brings about similar results (except for statements that print to the console, of course). Although, clojure repl does print all three.

Comment: This feels petty, but can the down-voter please explain the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The key observation is that it is not allowed to put in extra parenthesis in Scheme. In `(+ 1 2)` the expression `+` is evaluated and the result is a plus-function. That function is applied to 1 2 and you get the result 3.

In your example `(1)` means evaluate 1 and the result is 1. Then apply 1 to no arguments. And since 1 is not a function you will get an error.

In the example `(1 2 3)` your system attempts to apply 1 to the arguments 2 and 3 and get an error.

In short: Parenthesis in arithmetics is used to group an operation - in Scheme it means function application.

Finally: 1 2 3 is not a single expression but three expressions. The last of which evaluates to 3.